Take default value if not present
Have trait like below
trait MyTrait
{
    val country: String,
    val state: String,
    val commune: String = "nothing"

}

Now implementing MyTrait
case class ImplementTrait(
               country:String,
               state: String,
               //commune, how to provide commune's default value if commune is not provided while initialising  ImplementTrait
) extends MyTrait

For example
ImplementTrait(country, state), should work and because it will take commune default value
ImplementTrait(country, state, commune), should also work and because commune value is present now
any suggestions ?

While there is probably a way to make this work, this is very hard and complicated. vals in traits usually have all sorts of gotchas related to initialization, and abstracting over constructors is practically impossible in this language. - It is hard to see but in essence, you want a constructor to override or not a field based on an optional parameter.

I don't think there's something automatic that you can do easily, but you might want to consider something like the following:
object MyTrait {
  val DefaultCommune = "nothing"
}

trait MyTrait {
  def country: String
  def state: String
  def commune: String
}

final case class ImplementTrait(
    country: String,
    state: String,
    commune: String = MyTrait.DefaultCommune,
) extends MyTrait

assert(ImplementTrait("Germany", "Bayern").commune == "nothing")
assert(ImplementTrait("Mexico", "Yucatan", "Merida").commune == "Merida")

You can play around with this code here on Scastie.
Notice a couple of changes I made to your original suggestion, as further feedback:

No vals in traits: you know best of course for the use case you want to cover, but in general vals in trait tend to be discouraged as the order in which you inherit traits might affect the initialization of the class (see here for more details)
final case class: while you cannot inherit directly between case classes, you can have a normal class inherit from a case class -- this is very unlikely something you want and might affect value semantics, which is why it's usually recommended to make all case classes final (see here for more details)


commune: String = MyTrait.DefaultCommune, trying to understand this piece of code. How does it says that, take default value when it’s not present in constructor ?

@Maria case classes support default values and it's this syntax attribute: type = defaultValue instead of just attribute: type.

Methods and constructors (including those of case classes) can take a default parameter values, meaning that the specified default value will be used if the caller doesn't provide a parameter explicitly. See here for more details: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/default-parameter-values.html

@stefanobaghino, Is there any way if I remove commune from ImplementTrait and still works same way like your example ..?

Not that I know of.
